# Excel Pivot Table - Averaging by Category

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to create an average by category in a pivot table. This is the first time I've created a pivot table so sorry if the answer is staring me in the face. My raw data looks like:

```
Date,   Transaction type,   Description,     Paid out,   Paid in,    Balance,   Category
Mar-13, Visa,   SHOP,    £4.44, ,        £X,    Gifts
Mar-13, Visa,   SHOP,    £5.00, ,        £Y,    Children
Mar-13, Visa,   SHOP,    £6.00, ,        £Z,    Gifts
Mar-13, Visa,   CLOTHES SHOP YORK,   £8.00, ,        £A,    Clothing
Mar-13, Visa,   FOOD SHOP,   £11.96, ,       £B,    Food
```

My pivot table shows the information rolled up by Month and grouped by a category:

```
Row Labels  Sum of Paid out Sum of Paid in  Sum of Difference
2013            
   Jan        £Jan       £Jan                  £C
     Food       1              2                 -
     Car        2              3                     -
     Cash       6              6
   Feb         £Feb       £Feb                 £D
     Food       1              2
     Car        8              0
     Cash       2              3
```

The categories/data is made up in this case, but the desired outcome I'm after is to get an annual average, informing me how much comes in/out on average across the year per category... looking something like:

```
Row Labels  Sum of Paid out Sum of Paid in  Sum of Difference
2013
   Avg        £AvgIn     £AvgOut              £AvgDiff    
     Food       1              2                 -
     Car        5              1.5               -
     Cash       4              4.5        
   Jan        £Jan       £Jan                  £C
     Food       1              2                 -
     Car        2              3                 -
     Cash       6              6
   Feb         £Feb       £Feb                 £D
     Food       1              2
     Car        8              0
     Cash       2              3
```

Is this possible to achieve using a pivot table, as I can't seem to find a way to this at the moment using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it appears that your raw data is already grouped by month, you're able to do this pretty easily.  You need to re-arrange your data, however -- the months and the categories need to be on different axes.  For example, Category as ColumnLabels, with Values then Month as Row Labels. Then right-click one of the normal values for Paid Out, choose "Summarize Value As...", you'll see SUM is currently checked, just change to AVERAGE.  Repeat for one of the Paid In values.  The labels should change to help let you know if it worked.

[image]

Note that this will NOT work effectively if your source data comes in daily, for example.  With only one entry per month, the SUM and the AVERAGE of the single entry are identical.  This would not be the case if your raw data was daily (and you still grouped by month) -- you'd be switching from a monthly total to a daily average.

Comment: This is close to what I want, but not quite there. In your example I want 62.0, 59.0, 24.0 (values for Car) to be SUM'med from the data which is easy. The rows on the left, I'm actually grouping by year and month - so on the row above (Average of PaidOut) I want the average monthly spend on a car based on the numbers for the past year to be shown. Unfortunately I can't insert a formula manually in those cells as Excel won't allow it :(

Comment: I've just discovered, If I set it to use average, and collapse the region then it almost does what I want. It provides an average, but that is based on the # entries. So if I spend £10 on my car in Jan, £20 in Feb but nothing the rest of the year it gives me £15 as my average instead of £2.50

Comment: For your 2nd comment, the source data should include 3/1/2013 = 0, 4/1/2013 = 0, etc. to represent months with zero spend.  Otherwise, technically, the source data is incomplete.  Similar to a DBMS source, which needs the populated months JOINED against a complete list of time periods.

Comment: Thanks, I started to go down that route... putting in an entry for 'Car' for every month with a 0 value. I then noticed that actually if I run an average that it divides the SUM by the number of instances. So if I had 3 outgoing payments in Jan for my Car of £120 each and then nothing the rest of the year, the average would be £12, rather than £30. What I've currently decided to do, is to use this structure to SUM, and then create my own mini-table using the results of the pivot.

Comment: Right. It's confusing. The AVERAGE will always be at the individual cell level, meaning you can't sum up the month, then average that.  In a situation where you have 1 and only 1 entry per month, then AVERAGE = SUM per month and so you can get a grand total average.  But as soon as it gets more complex, as you're finding out, then yes, you're forced to do some calculations outside of the PivotTable.  If your source data is in a database (even Access), you can write SQL code that aggregates exactly the way you'd like, it's far more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I am currently using LibreOffice, which is just the free version of Excel on a mac. It is basically the same thing, but anyways, do you see the top bar where it says =AVERAGE(B8,C8,D8)? Well, that is how you can incorporate the functions within the table. This is actually a pivot table I had to do for my Java class. All you have to do is click on the cell you want to edit, type =, the function name, (in your case, AVERAGE should be fine) and then any other kinds of functions you use. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I'm aware of all the functions - could you give some example steps on how I would incorporate those into a Pivot table? For example a screenshot or two showing how to achieve the outcome I'm after? I'm not an excel novice, but I am a pivot table newbie.

Comment: I was looking for something more automatic, as I would have to create the average rows myself and then expand each group and select the cell that corresponds to the right category. Its a very labour intensive thing to do manually...